# Custom CheckBoxListFor Html helper. How do I bind to a viewmodel property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, model-binding, checkboxlist

I'm creating a custom Html helper for handling a checkbox list. I know there is a ton of info on this topic online, but I haven't seen much on trying to generate the HTML the way I am below.

### Desired Rendered HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
         <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="Genres" value="SF" />
             Science Fiction
         </label>
    </li>
    <li>
         <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="Genres" value="HR" />
             Horror
         </label>
    </li>
    <!-- more genres -->
</ul>
```

I am using distinct checkbox **values** rather than just booleans, because I want to take advantage of the fact that on form post, I would get a comma-separated list of **selected** values. For example, if Sci-Fi and Horror were both selected, I'd get `"SF,HR"`.

### View Model

```
public class MovieViewModel
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public string Year { get;set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Genres { get;set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GenreOptions { get;set; }
}
```

### View

In my view, I'd like to basically do this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Year)
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.Genres, Model.GenreOptions)
```

### Custom Html Helper

So, I started creating a custom Html helper, but I don't have a ton of experience with these, and this is where I need the help:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString CheckboxListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items)
    {
        if (items == null) return null;

        var itemsList = items.ToList();
        if (!itemsList.Any()) return null;

       // How do I get "Genres" name from the passed expression from viewmodel, without passing the hardcoded string "genres"?
        var checkboxGroupName = expression.what????

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<ul>");

        foreach (var item in itemsList)
        {
            var checkbox = $"<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"{checkboxGroupName}\" value=\"{item.Value}\" />";
            sb.Append($"<li class=\"checkbox\"><label>{checkbox} {HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Text)}</label></li>");
        }

        sb.Append("</ul>");

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
```

As you can see in the comment above, I don't know how to dynamically assign the viewmodel property name "Genres" to the checkboxes' `name` attribute, without hardcoding it. How do I get it from `model => model.Genres` expression?

Comment: `var checkboxGroupName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);`

Comment: As a side note, you not taking into account the checked state of the checkboxes (they will all be un-checked)

Comment: `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)` worked well, as did @Ehsan Sajjad's answer below! Thanks!  However, what about nested viewmodel scenarios? How do I get something like `<input name="Movie.Genres" />`?  And yes, you're right about the pre-existing state of checkboxes. Haven't gotten that far yet, I guess. Any pointers?

Comment: The answer by Ehsan Sajjad does not work for that - using `@CheckboxListFor(m => m.ComplexProperty.SomeProperty, ....)` will return `"SomeProperty"`. You need to use the code in my first comment which will give `"ComplexProperty.SomePropery"`

Comment: And there is a lot you should be changing to get correct 2-way model binding. No time just now, but I will ad an answer later. And do you also want the ability to achieve any validation (for example. selecting at least one checkbox)

Comment: Re: nested viewmodels, I was more thinking of situations like `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Movie)` where Movie is of type `MovieViewModel` which has Genres inside it, as described in my OP. Not sure if I'm describing the whole nesting thing well.  And yes, I suppose I will need to look into validation too.  Looking forward to seeing your approach on this!

Comment: That makes no sense - in order to bind to you `MovieViewModel`, your expression needs to be `m=> m.Genres`. If you have a parent view model containing property `MovieViewModel Movies`, then the expression is `m => m.Movies.Genres` (in which case `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)` will generate `name="Movies.Genres"` (but `metadata.PropertyName` will not)

Comment: Hmm, I see. What if I was using a custom EditorTemplate for MovieViewModel, and I was referencing it in a parent view as `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Movie)`? In that case I wouldn't want to put genres directly into the parent view, right, but would rely on the MovieViewModel editor template to render it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134128/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-jiveman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the property name, use

```
var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
```

which will give the fully qualified name, for example `@CheckboxListFor(m => m.Movies.Genres, ....)` will return `Movies.Genres`.

But to account for cases where your using an custom `EditorTemplate` for you model (which is a property of a parent model), then you also need to get the `HtmlFieldPrefix and if it exists, prepend it the name.

You current code does not give you correct binding, for example if `Genres` contains values matching the `Value` property of a `SelectListItem`, the associated checkbox should be checked when the view is rendered. Your code should be

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items)
{
    if (items == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("...");
    }
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    var model = metadata.Model as IEnumerable<string>;
    if (model == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("...");
    }
    // Get the property name
    var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    // Get the prefix in case using a EditorTemplate for a nested property
    string prefix = htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
    {
        name = String.Format("{0}.{1}", prefix, name);
    }
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        StringBuilder innerHtml = new StringBuilder();
        TagBuilder checkbox = new TagBuilder("input");
        checkbox.MergeAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        checkbox.MergeAttribute("name", name);
        checkbox.MergeAttribute("value", item.Value);
        if (model.Contains(item.Value))
        {
            checkbox.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");
        }
        innerHtml.Append(checkbox.ToString());
        TagBuilder text = new TagBuilder("span");
        text.InnerHtml = item.Text;
        innerHtml.Append(text.ToString());
        TagBuilder label = new TagBuilder("label");
        label.InnerHtml = innerHtml.ToString();
        TagBuilder li = new TagBuilder("li");
        li.AddCssClass("checkbox");
        li.InnerHtml = label.ToString();
        html.Append(li);
    }
    TagBuilder ul = new TagBuilder("ul");
    ul.InnerHtml = html.ToString();
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(ul.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks for including the complete solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the name of the property passed in the Html Helper from the parameter of type `Expression<Func<TModel,TProperty>>` that is passed using the [ModelMetaData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.aspx) class with the following lines of code:

```
var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
var checkboxGroupName = metadata.PropertyName;
```

Here is an article explaining [How to Create Custom Strongly Typed Html Helpers](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/389747/Custom-Strongly-typed-HtmlHelpers-in-ASP-NET-MVC) which might help you more.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Reading more now on the link you provided in order to figure out how to get a prefix in nested view model scenarios such as `<input name="Movie.Genres" />`.